# С помощью какой библиотеки Python можно нарисовать карту взаимосвязей таблиц и схем в БД? И как начать?

Tags: python, sql

Необходимо разработать скрипт на Python, который на вход принимает строку подключения к БД PostgreSQL, и создает карту взаимосвязей таблиц и представлений в базе данных. Учесть, что в базе данных есть несколько схем. Важно в карту связей включить какие таблицы используются в представлениях.

**Выходные данные:**
Карта связей в формате pdf/jpg. Указывать PK, FK и типы связей (1:n, n:n, 1:1) не обязательно:

[image: Схема БД]

Текстовый документ с описанием таблиц и взаимосвязей:

Table1
column1, column1Description
…
column100, column100Description
Linked Objects:
Table : table2, table3, table4

view1
column1, column1Description
…
column100, column100Description
column1, column1Description
…
column100, column100Description
Linked Objects:
Table : table1, table1, …
View  : view1, view2, …

…

Comment: Берёте карандаш, лист буммаги. ```\l```, ```\c database```,```\d table_name``` или ```\d+ table_name```. И описываете)

Comment: А можно посерьезнее?)

Comment: А по серьезнее ваш вопрос звучит -  "сделайте это вместо меня".  Что на этом сайте крайне не приветствуется. Ваш проект достаточно сложный. И на форуме его не объяснить, тем более вы этого сами даже не понимаете.  Так что либо самому сначала глубоко учить Python, что бы хоть понять, из каких непростых компонентов он состоит, либо на биржу фрилансеров, где вам сделают программу с большим удовольствием.

Comment: @passant что-то в последнее время много таких умников, да?

Comment: @passant Я лишь спросил с помощью какой библиотеки это можно сделать, а вы сразу кидаться на меня. Профессионалы блин. В интернете я не нашел информации по моему вопросу, вот решил называется спросить с чего начать. У вас ложное трактование моего вопроса

Comment: @AndrewHolovko Каких умников то? я лишь спросил про библиотеку? или на этом сайте даже такого нельзя спросить?